# Decrypt AES encrypted value in mysql generated using JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, cryptography, aes

How do I decrypt the AES encrypted value in MYSQL which is generated using JAVA code.
I'm doing password based encryption in Java, It usess AES as the underlying encryption algorithm and PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 to derive a key from a salt and password combination using the following code.

```
public String decryptAttr(String dbData, String key, String iv){
    
    try {
        String password = hash256(key);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
       
       //strip off the salt and iv
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new Base64().decode(dbData));
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[saltLength];
        buffer.get(saltBytes, 0, saltBytes.length);
        
        byte[] ivBytes1 = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
        buffer.get(ivBytes1, 0, ivBytes1.length);
        
        
        byte[] encryptedTextBytes = new byte[buffer.capacity() - saltBytes.length - ivBytes1.length];
        buffer.get(encryptedTextBytes);
        
        // Deriving the key
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(hash256Password.toCharArray(), saltBytes, iterationCount, keyLength);
        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes1));
        
        byte[] decryptedTextBytes = null;
        decryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);

        return new String(decryptedTextBytes);

    } catch (Excpetion e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return null;
}
```

I tried to decrypt the text using MySQL version 8.0.30 by substituting values in function `AES_DECRYPT('mytext','mykeystring', 'iv', 'pbkdf2_hmac','salt', 'iterationcount');`

SET session block_encryption_mode = 'aes-128-cbc';
SET @key_str = UNHEX(SHA2('4028c2ac696ba930016a2fc6765800e6',256));

EDIT : But getting error as iteration count less than 1000 not allowed. But if I pass `KDF` method as `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1` it says invalid name.

[image: Error image]

`mysql>  select AES_DECRYPT(SUBSTRING(HEX(FROM_BASE64('vzAXFDpaIRx0ctFWZ4hSl27c8vNApWgefBFVfj4wPYawFyrRkTPVJcjvKrheZR6UpwIArQ==')),73), @key_str, SUBSTRING(HEX(FROM_BASE64('vzAXFDpaIRx0ctFWZ4hSl27c8vNApWgefBFVfj4wPYawFyrRkTPVJcjvKrheZR6UpwIArQ==')),41,32), 'pbkdf2_hmac',SUBSTRING(HEX(FROM_BASE64('vzAXFDpaIRx0ctFWZ4hSl27c8vNApWgefBFVfj4wPYawFyrRkTPVJcjvKrheZR6UpwIArQ==')),1,40),2 ); ERROR 3236 (HY000): For KDF method pbkdf2_hmac iterations value less than 1000 or more than 65535 is not allowed due to security reasons. Please provide iterations >= 1000 and iterations < 65535`

Comment: *But getting error as below* The cause of that error message seems perfectly clear: you passed an iterations value of 2

Comment: @g00se Yes coz same iteration count was passed in java code

Comment: The message tells you exactly why you *can't* do that. What's more, since MySql is supporting AES, why are you doing it in Java at all?

Comment: @g00se There are two different teams , one is encrypting the data and other will use this data for some report purpose. As a developer , we do not want to share our encryption/decryption logic with them. Due to which we just want to give them a wrapper mysql function which can decrypt the data for other team. As the other team mostly works on mysql, we have to give mysql function instead of any API

Comment: Well, personally, I think that objective can't be met with symmetric encryption, which is problematic, not only for security reasons, but also for implementation reasons. Anyway, the simplest solution would seem to be to use a high enough iterations count in your Java to satisfy MySql